# Visual Studio Application not killed properly

Tags: process, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I run an application in Debug mode in Visual Studio and close it, the application does not get killed as expected. The window *closes successfully* but the *process keeps on running in the **background***.

As a result, when I try to launch the application again, Visual Studio gives me an error stating that **.dll is being used by another process**.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Terminate your application first before closing VisualStudio.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am not closing the Visual Studio, just terminating the application.